# shared library--libvw.so.0--is missing

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

all, I installed 'vowpal wabbit' package and also use 'make test' to test it. It shows everything is okay. However, when I input 'vw' in terminal, it has the following errors:

```
vw: error while loading shared libraries: libvw.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

My system is ubuntu12.04-64bit. Could anyone tell me how to solve this problem ? Thanks

Comment: Did you build this yourself, or get from a package? Can you rebuild the locate db with `/etc/cron.daily/mlocate` and then try `locate libvw.so.0`

Comment: I did it as you told me. I located the 'libvw.so.0'.

"/home/tqjustc/Downloads/vowpal_wabbit-7.2/vowpalwabbit/.libs/libvw.so.0" and

"/home/tqjustc/Downloads/vowpal_wabbit-7.2/vowpalwabbit/.libs/libvw.so.0.0.0"

"/home/tqjustc/Downloads/vowpal_wabbit-7.2/vowpalwabbit/.libs/libvw.so.0.0.0"  

"/usr/local/lib/libvw.so.0"   

"/usr/local/lib/libvw.so.0.0.0"

Comment: have you tried to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib` and run it?

Comment: @RichHomolka  What is this command used for ? thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the messaging back and forth, it looks like you have the library installed in /usr/local/lib. But your application doesn't know to look there for the library.

You can solve this in a few ways.

1. You can give special flags when you configure/build your project to tell your binary to check in /usr/local/lib. If you know how to set flags on build, you should set `LDFLAGS=-Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib`. This would make you rebuild though.
2. The runtime linker looks at an environment variable named `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to see what directories to check when looking for shared libraries. In this case, if you type `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib` and then run your program, it should work.
3. If you have multiple programs that need the /usr/local/lib directory, and you feel it is safe to include for everyone, you can set the runtime linker to try /usr/local/lib every time. You can drop a file in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` or edit `/etc/ld.so.conf` to add /usr/local/lib. This would affect every executable on your system, so I consider this one pretty advanced.

In short, you need to tell your program how to find the library. The easiest one for now is to set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable with `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib`

Answer (score 0):

Update:
I was setting up "Quagga" from source code. 
After installation, when I ran it, I got the error "cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". For my case, it was "libzebra.so.0" missing.

I used the "export" method as suggested by Rich in the above comment.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/foobar/lib
```

Where "/opt/foobar/lib" is your application specific shared library folder. For me, it was "/usr/local/lib/"

However, it didn't fix my issue. Then, to update the shared-library cache, I had to do a `ldconfig` to rebuild the shared-library cache. I found the suggestion from [This Github post](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/issues/466), You can also read details from [how-to-add-library-directory-toldconfig-cache](https://codeyarns.com/2014/01/14/how-to-add-library-directory-to-ldconfig-cache/)

Comment: While your link may provide a (partial?) answer, it is better if you post the information here,  and include the link for reference.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting.
I thought I should just include what additional command I had to use to make it work and give the reference of the main source.
However, I'll update my comment.